# How can I move the WordPress Revolution Slider Script Tags and Style Tags in a theme?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

According to W3C having a Revolution Slider in the body of your document is non compliant because the slider uses script tags and style tags that need to be in the header. I have looked inside of functions.php and other Revolution Slider PHP files, however I have not found a line of code that writes these scripts and styles to the page. Are these core files placed using JavaScript? Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
wp_header();
[[Desired placement of styles and scripts of Revolution Slider]]
</head>
[[current styles and scripts of Revolution Slider]]
```

Comment: Jason - What theme are you using with this slider? It many cases, themes are bundled with this slider and there may be a custom shortcode syntax that allows you to place it on various pages/posts.

Comment: I am using the paragon theme from ThemeForest.

Comment: Jason - I just validated the demo site and i'm not seeing an error that corresponds with what you are describing. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmoozpaper.com%2Fparagon_demo_1%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 It's fine to have javascript located within the body of a page.

Comment: I am not worried about the JavaScript as I am the CSS not being valid.

Comment: Jason, take a look at this question as it addresses the question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665268/correct-way-to-include-css-after-head

Comment: This one too, which has some details about load order and why you shouldn't do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957446/load-external-css-file-in-body-tag

Comment: So these articles explain that it is not good practice to put style tags in the body of an HTML document. I too agree that styles will still function. Again, is there a way I can move styles to the header using WordPress?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to edit the theme files since they likely have the styles for your revolution slider hard coded into them. Unfortunately that's a paid theme so you can't send it to me to look at.

Comment: Jason, the file you're looking for is: revslider_output_class.php. In wp_content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/. I can't seem to figure out how to get the styles to the head section. If anyone could help us out that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the Revolution Slider plugin folder go to `inc_php` >> `revslider_output.class.php`

Then remove lines 1648 to 1650 and 1654 to 1656.

You can then just put the following in your normal style sheet to replace the removed lines of code.

```
#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper .tp-loader.spinner3 div {
                background-color: #FFFFFF !important; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you insert the lines of codes that need to be deleted in case the file changes in future versions (so they can still be found if they are not 1648-1650 anymore)?

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2016 the line numbers for this code reference have changed. Also there is no need to remove the lines of code just comment them out and add to your CSS file.

Use Line numbers:
1745 - 1748
1752 - 1756

Or search for switch($use_spinner)

Add the CSS in the above post to your theme CSS Custom options or manually add to the style sheet.

Here is the code with the commented code.

```
switch($use_spinner){
            case '1':
            case '2':
                /* echo '<style type="text/css">'."\n";
                echo '  #'.$this->sliderHtmlID_wrapper.' .tp-loader.spinner'.$use_spinner.'{ background-color: '.$spinner_color.' !important; }'."\n";
                echo '</style>'."\n";
                */
            break;
            case '3':
            case '4':
            /*
                echo '<style type="text/css">'."\n";
                echo '  #'.$this->sliderHtmlID_wrapper.' .tp-loader.spinner'.$use_spinner.' div { background-color: '.$spinner_color.' !important; }'."\n";
                echo '</style>'."\n";
                */
            break;
            case '0':
            case '5':
            default:
            break;

        }
```